# Get single record on Django Rest Framework based on id

Tags: python, django, rest

I am getting the following response from my REST API at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/:

```
[
    {
        "id": "17442811-3217-4b67-8c2c-c4ab762460d6",
        "title": "Hair and Beauty"
    },
    {
        "id": "18a136b5-3dc4-4a98-97b8-9604c9df88a8",
        "title": "Plumbing"
    },
    {
        "id": "2f029642-0df0-4ceb-9058-d7485a91bfc6",
        "title": "Personal Training"
    }
]
```

If I wanted to access, a single record, I presume that I would need to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/17442811-3217-4b67-8c2c-c4ab762460d6 to access:

```
[
    {
        "id": "17442811-3217-4b67-8c2c-c4ab762460d6",
        "title": "Hair and Beauty"
    }
]
```

However, when I attempt this, it returns all of the records. How can I resolve this? This is my code so far:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^category/', views.CategoryList.as_view(), name="category_list"),
    url(r'^category/?(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', views.CategoryDetail.as_view(), name="category_detail")
]
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    List or create a Category
    HTTP: GET
    """
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer


class CategoryDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    List one Category
    """
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Class to serialize Category objects
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id')
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Category model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)
```

Comment: Why not using django rest framework `ModelViewSets`, that would solve your problem. please have a look at that on this link : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regex, `r'^category/'`, matches both a URL with and without a UUID.

You should anchor it at the end:

```
r'^category/$'
```

Additionally/alternatively, you can swap the order of those URL definitions, as Django will take the first one it matches.

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting the following error whenever I access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/17442811-3217-4b67-8c2c-c4ab762460d6/`: `AssertionError at /api/category/17442811-3217-4b67-8c2c-c4ab762460d6/`

Comment: I fixed the above error message by doing this: http://pastebin.com/MJdKBYsT in `views.py`. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking or what you did.

Comment: It's alright. I get what you mean. It's working after I made your adjustments. I was missing `queryset = Category.objects.all()` in my CategoryDetail view. initially but when I added it that made an error. I wanted to ask if CategoryDetail and CategoryList is necessary, as they appear to do the same thing. As seen in pastebin.com/MJdKBYsT.